# Retrieve single value key in token Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, token

I have a problem retrieving and displaying a single value of token like displaying the lastName in information token.

Here is my code to get API User profile:

```
// get API and Bearer token
let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/profile")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data else { return }
    //get information in token
    do {
         let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
          //  print(json)
        if let lastName = json["lastname"] as? [String] {
            print(lastName)
        }

    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}.resume()
```

I can not display lastName but I retrieve the information in raw the token like:

```
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "sub"
    ▿ value : 15 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : emailaddress
        - value : 
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : secretcode
        - value : $2a$10$IcNejUrpOk82mORSu4bQauLa12UP1dCjQ0y8hTLnEUl9otC.VLCCe
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : loginAttempts
        - value : 0
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - key : lastname
        - value : test
      ▿ 4 : 2 elements
        - key : numberisverified
        - value : 0
      ▿ 5 : 2 elements
        - key : created_at
        - value : 2018-07-11T14:38:29.266Z
      ▿ 6 : 2 elements
        - key : _id
        - value : 5b461665a6b67d046c42dc68
      ▿ 7 : 2 elements
        - key : countrycode
        - value : GN
      ▿ 8 : 2 elements
        - key : firstname
        - value : test
      ▿ 9 : 2 elements
        - key : birthday
        - value : 
      ▿ 10 : 2 elements
        - key : nationalformat
        - value : 625 25 92 39
      ▿ 11 : 2 elements
        - key : accountstatus
        - value : PENDING
      ▿ 12 : 2 elements
        - key : __v
        - value : 0
      ▿ 13 : 2 elements
        - key : internationalFormat
        - value : +224 625 25 92 39
      ▿ 14 : 2 elements
        - key : usernumber
        - value : +224625259239
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "exp"
    - value : 1532706259
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : "iat"
    - value : 1532702659
```

Help me to display single value **lastName = test** in my application.

i have this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjzSL.png)

Comment: Seems like lastname does not exist in the root of your `json` object.  Could you update your post with what is returned (print the `json` object)?  From your raw output, have you tried `json["sub"]["lastname"]`?

Comment: i updated my question you will see the error in link image

Thank You

Comment: Thanks @GeekThuG,  not quite what I was looking for though.  You commented out your print(json).  Thats what I was looking to see.  Nonetheless, I added an answer which I believe will work for you.  If not, please uncomment the print json line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last name seems to be under the `sub` property

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let sub = json["sub"] as? [String: AnyObject], let lastName = sub["lastname"] {
        print(lastName)
    }

} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer
    if let sub = json["sub"] as? [String:Any], let lastName = sub["lastname"] as? String {
            print(lastName)
}